# How can I check and change data in a mysql every 15 sec?

Tags: php, mysql, cron

In my web app, user is given 5 min to do some job, and after that 5 min, the job should be passed to other person. So, each job would have user_id and that user_id value has to be changed every 5 min. The thing is that there are multiple jobs, and we want to use 15sec interval for script to be periodically run to take care of this change. And job will passed to other person maximum of 4~5 times, and it will be disregarded after that.

The job & user data is stored in MySQL database.

My initial thought was to use cron-job with PHP script file that let the cron-job runs PHP script every 15 sec. PHP file will read the job table, select all the jobs which have time value past 5 min ago, and fetch them to other users (doesn't matter if one user get the all jobs or not). I just want to periodically run it without taking too much resources.. but is it a good idea? Wouldn't that take too much resources once the number of jobs increases?

While it does not have to be consistence (13~16 sec interval is just fine) we want that script does not stop.

Comment: Can you determine the appropriate user id dynamically at the time of the page request, instead of statically updating a user id field every 5 minutes?

Comment: You'll have to find something other than cron - cron can only do things once a minute (it doesn't do seconds).  I think the cron manual suggests regular programs / scripts that `wait` for the appropriate time in cases like this.

Comment: what about... setting the web page to refresh itself every couple minutes? or maybe there's an iframe on the page, and some ajax runs every minute or so to get fresh list. or, have the cron run the updaescript, which updates, then sleeps for 15 seconds, calls itself with a curl request, waits 15 more seconds, calls itself again (curl), then dies. or, what if instead of saving the user id in a field... what if the assigned user was derived from the age of the record... for the first five minutes, it belongs to user 234. for minutes 6-10 it belongs to user 876...

Answer (score 1):

Create a cronjob that reads the table status updated time.

-- show table status like `table`;

example: update_time: 2011-04-10 15:27:32

than you can do the logic in the cronjob to check that date. and if that date is greater than 15 seconds ago or whatever, than you have an updated records.